# Passing searched string ctivity to another activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to pass searched string to the other activity in SearchView.This string but according to this string the map is being searched and I want it to be sent when the button is clicked after the result is shown on the map

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_note);       
    searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.sviewCriticalNext);
    supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map1);
    btnCritical = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCriticalNext);
    btnZoom = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnZoom);
    btnZOut = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnZoomOut);
    }

searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {


            String location = searchView.getQuery().toString();

            getSearchedString(s);

            List<Address> addressList = null;
            if (location != null || !location.equals("")) {

                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(AddNoteActivity.this);

                try {
                    addressList = geocoder.getFromLocationName(location, 1);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Address address = addressList.get(0);
                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(address.getLatitude(), address.getLongitude());
                gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(location));
                gMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 10));

            }


            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
            return false;
        }
    });


    supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(AddNoteActivity.this);





}
```

Styled map ,it contains zoom(in-out) buttons

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    gMap=googleMap;
    gMap.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
    boolean success = googleMap.setMapStyle(new MapStyleOptions(getResources().getString(R.string.style_json)));

    if (!success) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Style parsing failed.");
    }




    btnZoom.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            gMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomIn());
        }
    });



    btnZOut.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            gMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomOut());
        }
    });


}
```

Searched string,i want to pass it

```
public String getSearchedString(String string){
    Toast.makeText(AddNoteActivity.this, "Result: "+string, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    passToActivity(string);
    return string;
}
```

Pass string when clikced but not working

```
private void passToActivity(String string) {

    btnCritical.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(AddNoteActivity.this, EndOfAddNoteActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("LOCATION",string);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Why not use SharedPreferences? That's a faster and more convenient approach.

Comment: Try passing location which you used above as :             String location = searchView.getQuery().toString();

Comment: When I don't add startActivity it returns null. If I add it, it starts  without waiting for the button to be clicked

Comment: It isn't clear what exactly your problem is. Please explain more clearly what isn't working as you want it to.

Comment: i want to pass searched string to  another activity when button clicked.passToAcctivity() method return null for  System.out.println("LOCATION"+getIntent().getParcelableExtra("LOCATION"));

Answer (score 0):

looking at comment:

> i want to pass searched string to another activity when button clicked.passToAcctivity() method return null for System.out.println("LOCATION"+getIntent().getParcelableExtra("LOCATION"));

i suggest take data from intnet by: `getIntent().getStringExtra("LOCATION")` or

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
if (bundle != null) {
   value = bundle.getString("LOCATION");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try this way: 
make global varialble:

`private String stringToPass`

then set button listener in onCreate() like this:

```
btnCritical.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(stringToPass != null) {
        Intent intent=newIntent(AddNoteActivity.this,EndOfAddNoteActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("LOCATION",stringToPass);
        startActivity(intent);}
}});
```

And finaly in onQueryTextSubmit do this: stringToPass = searchView.getQuery().toString();

Comment: It returning null

Comment: this will neither help nor does it answer the question